# Pytorch datatype/dimension confusion TypeError: 'Tensor' object is not callable

Tags: pytorch

This piece of code is originally written in numpy and I'm trying to utilise GPU computation by rewriting it in pytorch, but as I'm new to pytorch a lot of problems occured to me. Firstly I'm confused by the dimension of the tensors. Sometimes after operating on the tensors, only transposing the tensor would fix the problem, is there anyway I can stop doing **.t()**? The major problem here is that in the line **ar = torch.stack ...** the error "TypeError: 'Tensor' object is not callable " occurs. Any suggestion/correction would be appreciated. Thxxx

```
def vec_datastr(vector):

    vector = vector.float()
    # Find the indices corresponding to non-zero entries
    index = torch.nonzero(vector)
    index = index.t()

    # Compute probability
    prob = vector ** 2
    if torch.sum(prob) == 0:
        prob = 0
    else:
        prob = prob / torch.sum(prob)

    d = depth(vector)
    CumProb = torch.ones((2**d-len(prob.t()),1), device ='cuda')
    cp = torch.cumsum(prob, dim=0)
    cp = cp.reshape((len(cp.t()),1))
    CumProb = torch.cat((cp, CumProb),0)
    vector = vector.t()
    prob = prob.t()

    ar = torch.stack((index, vector([index,1]), prob([index, 1]), CumProb([index, 1]))) # Problems occur here
    ar = ar.reshape((len(index), 4))

    # Store the data as a 4-dimensional array
    output = dict()
    output = {'index':ar[:,0], 'value': ar[:,1], 'prob':ar[:,2], 'CumProb': ar[:,3]}

    return output
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ar = torch.stack(
    (index, vector([index, 1]), prob([index, 1]), CumProb([index, 1]))
)  # Problems occur here
```

`vector` is of type `torch.Tensor`. It has no `__call__` defined. You are going for `vector(...)` (`vector([index,1])`) while you should slice the data directly like this: `vector[index, 1]`. Same goes for `prob` and `CumProb`.

Somehow, you do it correctly for `ar` with `ar[:,0]` so it might be a typo